# Calculating totals with multiple occurrences of the same ID and values in same column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Recently I am coming across some strange tables and data.

I have a table that looks like the below image:

I would like to calculate the total hours worked and place in a new or alias column:

I would like to calculate the red header table to look like the blue table.

I am familiar with TSQL but never seen something like this and don't know where to start.

[image]

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you just want to use `SUM()`:

```
select userid, 
   sum(hrsworked) hrsworked
from yourtable
group by userid;
```

The `SUM()` function is an aggregate function that when used along with `GROUP BY` will get you the total hours worked for each `userId`

Answer (score 0):

You can start with [SUM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) and [GROUP BY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx)

```
select userid, sum(hrsworked) hrsworked
from TableName
group by userid
```